# Updating node contents from another file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to update node contents of a *.xml file from another file.
The folder structure is in the form [Folder_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaGN8.png)

I want to change the first node **label** of the xml file which is inside the **xml** folder by the contents of the first node **label** of the xml file which is inside the **meta** folder.
Below is the code that I've tried

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace XML_Parse
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }
        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                TextBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        void Button3Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string targetDirectory1 = TextBox1.Text;
            string[] xmlDir = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory1+@"\", "xml*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] xmlFilesArray1 = Directory.GetFiles(xmlDir[0], "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] xmlDir2 = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory1+@"\", "meta*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] xmlFilesArray2 = Directory.GetFiles(xmlDir[0], "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


            foreach (string xmlFile in xmlFilesArray1)
            {
                var FileInfo1 = new FileInfo(xmlFile);
                string FileLocation1 = FileInfo1.FullName;
                string file_name = Path.GetFileName(FileLocation1);
                foreach (var xmlFile2 in xmlFilesArray2)
                {
                    if (xmlFile2.Contains(file_name))
                    {
                        string path = Path.GetFullPath(xmlFile2);
                        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
                        string name = doc.Root.Element("Employee").Element("label").Value;
                        XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(FileLocation1);
                        doc2.Root.Element("Employee").SetElementValue("label", name);
                        doc2.Save(FileLocation1);
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Process complete");
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error message **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**
NOTE: The folder path given by the user in TextBox1 contains multiple folders with the above mentioned folder structure and I want to perform this operation on all folder which has the above mentioned folder structure.

Comment: Debug it. I can tell you your problem is happening before you even get to working with the xml.

Comment: It is giving the error in `string[] xmlFilesArray1 = Directory.GetFiles(xmlDir[0], "*.xml");` but I don't know how to repair it.

Comment: The line before that did not get any directories, `xmlDir` is empty so you cannot reference index zero.

Comment: I can't figure out why is `xmlDir` showing empty, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You application might be looking into the folder where the assembly was deployed and is unable to find the files. Try to enter full path for the directory in your TextBox1.

Answer (score 0):

the first use of `xmlDir[0]` is where you are getting the exception.  The previous line must be returning 0 directories matching your criteria.

Set a break point on the line that assigns `xmlDir` and launch in the debugger.  When you step over the line you will see zero elements in `xmlDir`.  You are trying to access the item at element index 0 (first element) but there are none, so you get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Best practice is to check via `xmlDir.Length > 0` or `xmlDir.Any()` before trying to access the first element.

Comment: I've got rid of that problem(I've updated my post), but now I'm getting a new error **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** on the line of code `string name = doc.Root.Element("Employee").Element("label").Value;`

Comment: When the break point is on that line in the debugger hover over each property with your mouse. One of them will say null. That is where your problem is.  Probably the xml doesn’t have the element in the position you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//get all directories from basepath 
       string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(basePath);


      //Loop through each parent directory and get each matching xml file from it
         List<string[]> newList = filesindirectory.Select(folder => (from item in Directory.GetDirectories(folder, "meta", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(item => Directory.GetFiles(item, "*.xml"))
                         .ToList()
                         .SelectMany(x => x)
                     let sx = Directory.GetDirectories(folder, "xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(items => Directory.GetFiles(items, "*.xml"))
                         .ToList()
                         .SelectMany(s => s)
                         .Any(s => Path.GetFileName(s) == Path.GetFileName(item))
                     where sx
                     select item).ToArray()
                 .Concat((from xmlItem in Directory.GetDirectories(folder, "xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(item => Directory.GetFiles(item, "*.xml"))
                         .ToList()
                         .SelectMany(xs => xs)
                     let sx = Directory.GetDirectories(folder, "meta", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(items => Directory.GetFiles(items, "*.xml"))
                         .ToList()
                         .SelectMany(sc => sc)
                         .Any(sc => Path.GetFileName(sc) == Path.GetFileName(xmlItem))
                     where sx
                     select xmlItem).ToArray()))
             .Select(xmlFiles => xmlFiles.ToArray()).ToList();


         //loop through each element of the jagged array
         foreach (string[] path in newList)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < path.Length / 2; j++)
             {
                 XDocument doc = Xdocument.Load(path[j]);
                 string name = doc.Root.Element("Emp").Element("lbl").Value;
                 XDocument doc2 = Xdocument.Load(path[(path.Length / 2) + j]);
                 doc2.Root.Element("Employee").SetElementValue("label", name);
                 doc2.Save(path[(path.Length / 2) + j]);
             }
         }
```

Credit to **JapanDave**